# How to create a floor with Chipmunk library

Tags: ruby, game-engine, game-physics, chipmunk, libgosu

I'm using Ruby and, of course, the Ruby bindings to Chipmunk as well as the [Chingu](https://github.com/ippa/chingu)/[Gosu](http://www.libgosu.org/) game libraries. Seems like the syntax is different but otherwise I assume it's the same as Chipmunk C. How do I make a floor? I tried the following:

```
space = CP::Space.new
space.damping = 0.9
space.gravity = CP::Vec2.new(0, 50)
body = CP::StaticBody.new
shape_array = [CP::Vec2.new(0, 400), CP::Vec2.new($window.width, 400), CP::Vec2.new($window.width, 390), CP::Vec2.new(0, 390)]
shape = CP::Shape::Poly.new(body, shape_array, CP::Vec2.new(0,0))
shape.collision_type = :floor
space.add_body(body)
space.add_shape(shape)
```

What happens is objects hit the floor and kind of wiggle for a split second, then pass right through. I want them to land on the floor, maybe even bounce up a little (depending on the object). But not go through the floor. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work, I had to remove the line:

```
space.add_body(body)
```

Static bodies can't be added to space.